# Need a little direction

Tags: database

So I have a general knowledge of computers and networking however I don’t know code at all. I am the type of person that takes on complex issues and figuring them out from scratch. I work in law enforcement and one of the things I have to deal with is cars that get impounded. Our office is on a paper system and nothing is digitized. My question is what coding would I need to learn? Would it be a combo of things such as a language and knowledge about databases. Essentially I’m asking for a supply list what would you suggest someone with no experience to learn in able to complete a program that could track and manage cars and fees for a small department.

Comment: If you are really just starting out, then I suspect that a really simple system created in Microsoft Access might be the the easiest way to start. It would give you a start in designing tables to match your requirements, and would have the advantage of keeping everything local, as I suspect your department might have issue with saving things onto the web. But you will get 100 opinions about what to start with! Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not really suitable for StackOverflow but maybe https://stackexchange.com/. Anyhow, to digitize everything you would need a UI (User interface) that could be made in HTML and CSS and you would also need to learn javascript to handle the logic in the browser.

For the database, I would go with https://Firebase.com since its free tier is awesome and good for your use case. It is a database as a service so you wouldn't need to learn another special language since you could interact with the database using Javascript.

Summary: HTML CSS JAVASCRIPT